Why does my iCal event import as UTC instead of the specified time zone?
I've created an iCal feed for a calendar on a website. The date/time in the markup is correct but when I try to subscribe to it, all the times are offset -5 hours, which is the same as the time zone offset. Here's an example with a single event:
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Expo Center//NONSGML Agenda v1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:Expo Center Events
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/Chicago
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Chicago
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZNAME:CDT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0600
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
DTSTART:19700308T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZNAME:CST
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0600
DTSTART:19701101T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:485779@Expo Center
DTSTAMP:20240823T154906
DTSTART;TZID=America/Chicago:20241003T100000
DTEND;TZID=America/Chicago:20241003T173000
SUMMARY:Original Sewing and Quilt Show 
DESCRIPTION:
URL:https://www.sewingexpo.com/Events/Nashville-TN
LOCATION:Entire Building
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

The time specified here, 10:00AM, is correct but after importing it becomes 5:00AM. What am I doing wrong?
